# CodeIgniter: rewriting URL's with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've build an application using CodeIgniter with several controllers

I want the application URL to look "pretty" by using .htaccess files. 
All controllers seem to work just fine except for the controller that is set as default in the "application/config/routes.php" file

My .htaccess file looks like this:

> RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteBase / 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I have also set the config.php file like this

> $config['index_page'] = '';

In the server logs I'm getting errors like this:

> [Fri Nov 29 10:32:11 2013] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] mod_security: Filtering against POST payload requested but payload is not available [hostname "app.***.nl"] [uri "/user/profile"]

On the development server everything worked just fine, but ever since the app is on the production server it doesn't work with the .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^codeigniter.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```